# Linux custom UART driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, uart

I have written a simple serial UART driver for 16550A based chipset, it is getting its IO regions & IRQ no. But interrupts are not getting generated.

Any pointers in this regard, I have made all the customary initilization of registers.

Comment: The 16550 has a buffer that will trigger an interrupt when it is filled to a certain level.  Are you feeding it enough data in your tests to trigger the interrupt?

Comment: Ya I'm filling the hardware buffer to its level. Actually I now got

Comment: I used to remove the existing drivers using rmmod 8250_pnp & rmmod 8250. Now i have completely moved all of them out & did depmod -a. With this now I'm able to generate inetrrupts...